# nginx_http_push_module and databases

Tags: php, database, nginx, comet, push

i am a newbie of nginx , and i am using nginx as a comet server by nginx_http_push_module

i have two question:

1,how can i save the messages which recieved by nginx_http_push_module into databases  ?

2,how can i get listeners list of a channel ?

thanks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1,how can i save the messages which recieved by nginx_http_push_module into databases ?

You have to subcribe to the channel you're interested in on the server side, and store each message in the database as they arrive.

You could use [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) in PHP, for example, to repeatedly long-poll the channel (you will have to set an appropriate timeout and the right caching headers: *If-None-Match* and *If-Modified-Since*).

> 2,how can i get listeners list of a channel ?

Side note: [nginx http push module protoco](http://pushmodule.slact.net/protocol.html)l is dead simple, this is **not** [bayeux](http://svn.cometd.com/trunk/bayeux/bayeux.html). A subscriber/listener in this module is simply an *active* HTTP connection on a subscriber URL. For example, if you use [interval-polling](http://pushmodule.slact.net/#config-push_subscriber) instead of long polling, you will be counted as a subscriber only for the (very) short time during when the connection is established.

This is why a list of listeners of a channel doesn't make a lot of sense with this module.

You can however get the number of active subscribers of a channel by issuing a *GET* request to the publishing URL, but I seriously doubt you could do anything with this.

Answer (score 0):

1 - nginx does not receive any message from clients, only from your application at publish url which should be protected.

2 - you can implement some javascript tricks with body.onload and unload to create a chat user list for example.